# Linux - Optimize shell script count files in several folders

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script to count files daily in ~ 10 folders. When the script running, it take too long time to finish. Example: 3 hours for finish count in 3 folders, but when I using command

```
ll | grep "condition" | wc -l
```

in the folder it take ~10 seconds/folder :(

I think problem with my script, it not optimize. Please share your experience about that, thank you.

**input_path_CDR.txt**

```
/bgw_vol01/backup/cdr/folder1
/bgw_vol01/backup/cdr/folder2
/bgw_vol01/backup/cdr/folder3
...
```

**script_count_CDR.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/bgw_vol01/script/input_path_CDR.txt"

i=1
while read line; do
    FILES=$(find $line -type f)
    hostname=$HOSTNAME
    dat=$(date -d '-1 day' '+%g%m%d')
    
    for f in $FILES
    do
        FILECOUNT="$(find $line | grep "$dat" | wc -l)"
    done
    echo $HOSTNAME"|"$line"|"$dat"|"File count: $FILECOUNT >> output_`date -d '-1 day' '+%g%m%d'`.txt
    
    i=$((i+1))
done < $file
```

Comment: Why don't you use `find "$line" -name "*$dat*"`?

Comment: The `echo` statement should be inside the loop. Otherwise you're just echoing the count of the last file.

Comment: Why do you assign `dat` inside the loop? It doesn't change. And why do you need the `hostname` variable at all?

Comment: You're never doing anything with `$f` in the `for f in $FILES` loop. What's the reason for that loop?

Comment: if `ll | grep "condition" | wc -l` does what you want then why not use it in the script?

Comment: I remove hostname, I want to export like this:
20211104|folder1|File count: 500
20211104|folder2|File count: 700
20211104|folder3|File count: 850

Comment: ll | grep "condition" | wc -l
=> I want to count file in folder, with condition, because have many file, I just want to count file with the day -1

Answer (score 0):

For starters please let me point the issues I see in your script

```
...
i=1   
while read line; do
    FILES=$(find $line -type f)    # you`re putting all found file names in this variable(!)
    hostname=$HOSTNAME    # is it expect to change? if not put it before loop
    dat=$(date -d '-1 day' '+%g%m%d')  # same thing
    
    for f in $FILES   # now you are looping over every single found file, which is unnecessary  
    do
        FILECOUNT="$(find $line | grep "$dat" | wc -l)"  # lets say you have 100 files, it will set this variable 100 times with same value(!)
    done
    echo $HOSTNAME"|"$line"|"$dat"|"File count: $FILECOUNT >> output_`date -d '-1 day' '+%g%m%d'`.txt    # it`s not really an issue but you have $dat variable, so why not to use it in out file name?
    
    i=$((i+1))   # if it`s not used, remove it
done < $file
```

Now, I propose to change it into something like this:

```
...
hostname=$HOSTNAME
dat=$(date -d '-1 day' '+%g%m%d')
while read line; do
    FILECOUNT=$(find $line -type f -name "*${dat}*" | wc -l)   # we are looking in $line dir, only for files having $dat in file name and count them
    echo "${HOSTNAME}|${line}|${dat}|File count: ${FILECOUNT}" >> output_${dat}.txt
done < $file
```